# Secure Controller's methods using xml instead of annotations in Symfony 2

Tags: xml, security, annotations, symfony

I am developing a bundle right now, which eventually I would like to distribute as a third party bundle. In this bundle I have controllers which methods I need to secure, such as to logged in users and such.

I have found [two methods](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/securing_services.html) to secure these routes, one being annotations and the other manually checking in the file controller logic itself. Both of these methods aren't decoupled for my tastes, Requiring the files to be edited to change the role if the developers have customized roles is bad, in my opinion.

I would like to move this configuration out to a xml file, but I have not found any documentation or examples to do this.

If it is not currently possible, what would you suggest to force secure routes but still be easily editable and update-able?

Answer (score 2):

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) (the bundle that handles method access control) can be configured via annotations or (in the master branch) by adding expressions to the bundle's configuration in config.yml/config.xml:

```
jms_security_extra:
    method_access_control:
        "ProductManager::bulkDelete$": "hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

If you want to use this technique to secure controllers you will also need JMSDiExtraBundle installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well that annotation is provided by [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle). You can view its [documentation](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) to find answers (under Configuration and Method Security Authorization paragraphs).

P.S. Just a quick note: any develop that will be using your bundle won't need to (and shouldn't) edit anything inside your actual bundle code no matter how you will decide to configure it, they will instead extend your bundle and configure the extension (see how [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) is configured for reference)

P.S. Lol, basically same answer at the same time as Kris :D